# Парсер на Scrapy перестал работать (429). Еще несколько дней назад код работал

Tags: python, парсер, scrapy

Имею парсер для wildberries, он собирал все товары. Исправно работал, но вчера почему то вместо стандартного вывода результатов полезли красные сообщения, ошибки и отказы в запросах. Я уже регулировал DOWNLOAD_DELAY и USER_AGENT однако не смог добиться никакого результата.
Ниже прикладываю код и трейсбек. Очень прошу помощи, пожалуйста.
Опять же повторю, вот этот самый код еще двва дня назад работал, использовал его примерно месяц.

```
BASE_URL = 'https://www.wildberries.ru'
CATALOG_URL = 'https://napi.wildberries.ru/api/menu/getburger?includeBrands=False'
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 0

alert_list = []
denied_list = []


def get_request(url):
    while True:
        request = requests.get(url)
        if request.status_code == 200:
            time.sleep(DOWNLOAD_DELAY)
            return request
        elif request.status_code in (401, 404):
            denied_list.append(url)
            return None
        else:
            time.sleep(2)


def expand_catalog(full_catalog, prefix=''):
    result = []
    for category in full_catalog:
        new_prefix = prefix + '/' + category['name'] if prefix else category['name']
        if category['childNodes']:
            result.extend(expand_catalog(category['childNodes'], new_prefix))
        else:
            if category['pageUrl'].startswith('/api/'):
                category_url = BASE_URL + category['pageUrl'][4:] + '?page='
                result.append((category_url, new_prefix))
            else:
                alert_list.append(category['pageUrl'])
    return result


class WbSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'wb_spider'
    custom_settings = {'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': DOWNLOAD_DELAY}

    def start_requests(self):
        for catalog in expand_catalog(get_request('https://napi.wildberries.ru/api/menu/getburger?includeBrands=False').json()['data']['catalog'][:-4]):
            r = get_request(catalog[0] + '1')
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,features="lxml")
            try:
                products_count = ''.join(soup.find('span', class_='goods-count').text.strip().split()[:-1])
            except AttributeError:
                denied_list.append(catalog[0] + '1')
                continue
            pages_count = min(int(float(products_count) / 100) + 1, 1000)
            for page_id in range(1, pages_count + 1):
                yield scrapy.Request(catalog[0] + str(page_id), callback=lambda r: self.parse_page(r, catalog[1]))

    def parse_page(self, response, category_title):
        for product_card in response.css('div.product-card__wrapper'):
            name = product_card.css('span.goods-name::text').extract_first().strip()
            product_link = BASE_URL + product_card.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first()
            price = product_card.css('.lower-price::text').extract_first().strip()
            old_price = product_card.css('.price-old-block del::text').extract_first()
            if not old_price:
                old_price = price
            sale = product_card.css('span.product-card__sale::text').extract_first()
            if not sale:
                sale = '-0%'
            # print(name, category_title, product_link, price, old_price, sale)
        print(category_title, '; PAGE: ', response.url.split('=')[-1])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(WbSpider)
    process.start()
```

Traceback:

```
2022-02-08 15:27:18 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.7.1.0, libxml2 2.9.12, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 21.7.0, Python 3.10.0 (tags/v3.10.0:b494f59, Oct  4 2021, 19:00:18) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 21.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021), cryptography 36.0.1, Platform Windows-10-10.0.19042-SP0
2022-02-08 15:27:18 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2022-02-08 15:27:18 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 2}
2022-02-08 15:27:18 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 1d5f25875625f51f
2022-02-08 15:27:18 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2022-02-08 15:27:18 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2022-02-08 15:27:18 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2022-02-08 15:27:18 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2022-02-08 15:27:18 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2022-02-08 15:27:18 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-02-08 15:27:18 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2022-02-08 15:27:18 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): napi.wildberries.ru:443
2022-02-08 15:27:18 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://napi.wildberries.ru:443 "GET /api/menu/getburger?includeBrands=False HTTP/1.1" 200 None
2022-02-08 15:27:20 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.wildberries.ru:443
2022-02-08 15:27:22 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://www.wildberries.ru:443 "GET //catalog/zhenshchinam/odezhda/bluzki-i-rubashki?page=1 HTTP/1.1" 404 None
2022-02-08 15:27:22 [scrapy.core.engine] ERROR: Error while obtaining start requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Мвидео\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 129, in _next_request
    request = next(slot.start_requests)
  File "C:\Users\Мвидео\PycharmProjects\test\main.py", line 49, in start_requests
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'content'
2022-02-08 15:27:22 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2022-02-08 15:27:22 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'elapsed_time_seconds': 3.673449,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 8, 12, 27, 22, 68876),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 8, 12, 27, 18, 395427)}
2022-02-08 15:27:22 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Так же во время работы вылезают такие сообщения вместо информации о товарах

Comment: 2022-02-08 15:31:10 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/zhenshchinam/odezhda/bluzki-i-rubashki?page=524> (failed 1 times): 429 Unknown Status
2022-02-08 15:31:10 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <429 https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/zhenshchinam/odezhda/bluzki-i-rubashki?page=497>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed

Comment: Зайдите с вашего IP на сайт, вам скорее всего капчу предлагают

Comment: Нет, капчу не предлагают. Это я проверял